# Why does invoking the put method on a Map result in a NullPointerException when the variable has already been instantiated?

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception, put

1. In the first iteration through the for loop, why does the method throw a NPE on line 15, but yet, on the next iteration, it still shows that the key and value from the first iteration had been added to the map?
2. Why is there even a NPE even being thrown? According to the API, the NPE is thrown if I had the specified key/value passed in are null. I dont seem to have committed either of the 2 scnearios listed.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Please post your code *inside* the method? A screenshots is harder to read.

Comment: Also please consider giving the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException`. It will typically show where in the code NPE is generated. You can get the stacktrace by adding `e.printStackTrace()` into your catch blocks

Comment: To add to the comment by @JoachimSauer, screenshot are impossible to read behind some corporate firewalls...

Comment: @madth3 - Actually the output on the command prompt screen is consistent with the code. It's confusing since the poster included the output of a compile error he fixed, but the command prompt shows a recompile and an execute with the output that would be expected.

Answer (score 3):

Your `NullPointerException` is actually occurring on the line

```
(int) integer = mapper.put(x,1);
```

The reason for this is that you are putting a value into your Map, but nothing was previously mapped there, therefore null is returned from the put method. By autoboxing, we then attempt to take this `Integer` object to an `int` primitive and get a `NullPointerException`.